# CSS not showing all rules

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap jumbotron as a header for the my webpage and I have my own layout.css but not all my rules for .jumbotron are working. When I tried setting `margin-bottom: 0px;` it doesn't show up in my browsers developer tools, not even as cross out. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**index.html** - head and header with jumbotron class:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/layout.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<header class="jumbotron container-fluid">
    <h1> Catalog App </h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default btn-login" onclick="location.href='/login/'">Login</button>
</header>
```

**layout.css** - .jumbotron:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-color: #195e8c;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

**Developer Tools** - not showing margin-bottom:

[image: Chrome Developer tools]

I made sure everything is saved and reloaded the server. Its ran on a simple Flask python server if that at all matters.

Comment: Try to put your CSS files after the bootstrap css

Comment: can you reproduce it for us?

Comment: @BigMonkey89WithaLeg They already are linked after the bootstrap CSS

Comment: @MichaelCoker Not sure how to reproduce it, all I did was make a basic Flask server, I included my head and the relevant code along with a picture of my developer tools if that helps give more info

Comment: And you can navigate to `css/layout.css` and see the `margin-bottom` listed there? Have you checked to see if you have any (potentially hidden) special characters in that file?

Comment: I misunderstood you so my original comment was wrong, I navigated to css/layout.css and saw that the css was the same as when I first set the flask app so I reset the flask app and restarted the server and it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask wasn't reloading the CSS file, since in my server.py file **layout.css** is static it is set once when the app is first set. I set the **FLASK_APP** again and reloaded the server and it solved the problem.

*To have a flask server refresh including the css turn off your browsers cache and turn on flask debug `export FLASK_DEBUG=1`*

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `!important` to your margin property

```
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #195e8c;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Comment: I saw this solution in another similar post but they warned against using it and said to never use it unless the parent uses it (I checked bootstrap.css and it does not use !important), what are the potential problems with using !important?
EDIT: Tested this and the margin-bottom rule is still not showing

Comment: Many bootstrap css default properties need `!important` to be override. I think there's not any relevant problem, you just need to use `!important` if you need to override it again.

Comment: I tested this and it still doesn't show up in the browser or developer tools

Comment: Also tried that, no luck. I also check to make sure none of the elements within the header have a margin outside the header.

Comment: Seem that the solution is to remove the default property from the bootstrap.css  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337758/gap-between-nav-and-jumbotron-in-bootstrap